# Update and attach entity with json column in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my class

```
public class UserSetting
{
    [Key]
    public int UserSettingId { get; set; }
    public string UserLanguage { get; set; }
    public string HelpTourList { get; set; }
    public CalenderTypeEnum UserCalender { get; set; }
    public NumericFormatEnum NumericFormat { get; set; }
    public List<AggridStates> AggridStates { get; set; }
    public int FontSize { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

The `AggridStates` is a JSON column and its configuration is

```
builder.OwnsMany(author => author.AggridStates, c=> c.ToJson());
```

When I fetch data with tracking entity then I update `AggridStates`, everything is ok:

```
var obj = BaseService.GetAll().Where(c => c.UserId == null).FirstOrDefault();
obj.AggridStates = new List<AggridStates>() { input };
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But when I fetch entity without tracking and then I attach entity with this code

```
var obj = BaseService.GetAll().Where(c => c.UserId == null).FirstOrDefault();
obj.AggridStates = new List<AggridStates>() { input };
context.Attach(entity);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

then my JSON column is not updated.

Comment: Did you try `QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll` ?